# Downloaded File: Not able to save to local drive

Tags: vba, excel

I've a VBA script which download files from a website but when the PDF file is being  downloaded and when I tried to save it to my local drive of the system I'm getting an error called ***run time error '3004': Write to file failed***. My code is as following:

```
    Sub login()
        Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
        Dim uid As String
        Dim pwd As String
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim objCollection As Object
        Dim buttonCollection As Object
        Dim ieElement As Object
        Dim ieButton As Object
        Dim WinHttpReq As Object
        Dim oStream As Object
        Dim MyURL As String

    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Set sh = Sheets("Indeed Resume Download")
    Set rng = sh.Range("A2")

    uid = rng.Value
    pwd = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Dim j As Long
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer 'Initialize internet object
    objIE.Navigate "https://secure.indeed.com/account/login?service=my&hl=en_IN&co=IN&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.co.in%2F"
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.Document.all.signin_email.Value = uid
    objIE.Document.all.signin_password.Value = pwd

    Set ieElement = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("sg-btn sg-btn-primary btn-signin")(0)
    ieElement.Click

    For j = 2 To sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Row

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

        MyURL = sh.Range("XDA" & j).Value

        objIE.Navigate MyURL

        Do While objIE.Busy = True
            DoEvents
        Loop

    Set ieButton = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button download_button"(0)
    ieButton.Click

    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", MyURL, False
    WinHttpReq.Send
    MyURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody

        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile ("D:\Downloaded Indeed Resume - Store")
        oStream.Close

        Next j
        Set objIE = Nothing    
    End Sub
```

Comment: `oStream.SaveToFile ("D:\Downloaded Indeed Resume - Store")` are you missing the file name here?

Comment: I believe this has to do with their website denying external access unless it's from the browser session you log on to. As a workaround, I retrieve the PDFs from IE's cache, once the PDF is displaying from the browser session.

Comment: Thanks Tim Williams for your response, it really helped a lot however now the file which I've downloaded is being downloaded in corrupt format it says "Format Error: Not a PDF or corrupted". Or when I'm trying by just oStream.Save method, file is not being downloaded at all.